# How to hide ignored files in GitKraken?

Tags: gitkraken

so I have updated my version of IntelliJ and Jetbrains decided to create new files and folders on my code folder. (see screenshot below)

I don't really want Jetbrains/IntelliJ clogging up my repo so I decided to add this entry on the .gitignore on the parent folder (e.g. /Users/myuser/Documents/myrepo/.gitignore)

```
##########################
## Jetbrains/IntelliJ
##
.idea/
.idea_modules/
*.iml
```

My problem with Gitkraken is that it continues to show all files and folder (as unstaged) inside "/Users/myuser/Documents/myrepo/.idea" even after I restart the app. I'm not sure if this matters but I am using the Gitkraken macOS version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

1. Commit your `.gitignore` first. (Just a guess)
2. There is an option in GitKraken to ignore files individually, Right-Click (on the unstaged file) -> Ignore. This will add it to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a global ignore file like what is demonstrated [here](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/setting-up-a-global-gitignore-file/)

GitKraken reads the global ignore file as well as the ignore files in the repo.

It does require a little bit of command line use but not much.

1. create a file in your home directory `touch ~/.global_gitignore`
2. add things like the `.idea` and other things in that file you never want in any repos (including OS specific things) see https://github.com/github/gitignore for many helpfil things to add
3. run the following command `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.global_gitignore`
4. Enjoy never needing to exclude them from your repos again.